# Will this cause a WAR hazard?

Tags: assembly, arm

Quick, and perhaps silly question, but here it is nevertheless. Writing to a register immediately after reading from it may cause a hazard if if we try to write to a register before its value could be fetched by the previous instruction. Does the following instruction then cause a hazard on an ARM chip:

```
add r3, r0, r3
```

which essentially is `r3 += r0`?

Will this be a hazard on NEON? Ex:

```
vadd.32 q3, q0, q3
```

Comment: A quick reading of chapter 16 of the [Cortex-A8 TRM](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.ddi0344b/BABFFGIG.html) [PDF](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.ddi0344b/DDI0344.pdf) suggest that - if other ARM chips are similar - they should both complete in a single cycle, but that you might be hindering dual issue (but answering that requires context).

Comment: A way to test for it is to make two sample programs which try `add r3, r0, r3` and `add r1, r0, r3` inside a loop measuring the execution time. After _many_ iterations compare the times: if they're equal there's no hazard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no WAR hazard.

The destination register is not needed before the source registers are; the requirement that `r3` be available for reading as an input is at least as strong as the requirement that it be available for writing to.  In short, there's no reason to avoid this construct.

Answer (score 1):

There are no stalls updating one of the operands. WAR hazards are actually pretty unusual because writes usually occur later in the pipeline than reads.